# Multiple Istio instances in one cluster

Tags: istio

We have quite large clusters with different independent organizations. Therefore we would like to have an installation of istio per organisation.

**Question: Is this possible at all?**

I know I can install the control plane separately in custom namespaces. However, when I'd like to install istio using the [helm chart], I don't know how to configure it respectively for concurrent installations of isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have one ingress controller by namespace, you need to use `helm install --namespace` to specify the desired namespace.

If you want your ingress controller check only local namespaced rules, you need to use the option:

```
  # Whether to restrict the applications namespace the controller manages;
  # If not set, controller watches all namespaces
oneNamespace: false
```

This option needs to be true.

Comment: Would it be possible to have multiple namespaces controlled? Our current setup is that we have multiple organizations with multiple namespaces each. However the organizations should not share the same service mesh.